# How to correctly chunk two seperate type of JSON data in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm attempting to iterate through a JSON file, retrieving the calorie count for each item and then sorting by meal and day (in total, there are only five days of data). Here is an example of an object in the array.

```
"Date": "Thursday",
"Name": "Shredded Chicken",
"Icon": "Chicken",
"Type": "Dinner",
"Quantity": 85,
"Units": "Grams",
"Calories": 90
```

Currently,  the totals for `breakfastCalories`, `lunchCalories`, `dinnerCalories`, and `snackCalories` are being added together (i.e. Monday's breakfastCalories is being added to Tuesday's breakfastCalories, and so on).

**GOAL** The intended result is to have an array for *each* day, listing the total breakfastCalories, et al. for that day. This *only* worked for day 1,  `print(calTotal[18])` returns  `[465,380,530,153,1528,899]`, which is the correct array of values for `breakfastCalories, lunchCalories, dinnerCalories, snackCalories, grossCalories, netCalories`.

```js
let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]; //currently does nothing
let calTotal = [];

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    loadJSON("finalJSON.json", cbSuccess, cbFail);
}

function draw() {
    //to be utilized
}

function cbFail(data) {
    print("Error loading JSON File");
    print(data);
}

function cbSuccess(data) {
    let myData = data; //load our JSON array
    let calories = 0; //set a 0 starting value for calories
    let breakfastCalories = 0;
    let lunchCalories = 0;
    let dinnerCalories = 0;
    let snackCalories = 0;
    let burnedCalories = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) { //count number of total entries in the dataset

        if (myData[i].Type == "Breakfast") {
            breakfastCalories += myData[i].Calories;
        }
        else if (myData[i].Type == "Lunch") {
            lunchCalories += myData[i].Calories;
        }
        else if (myData[i].Type == "Dinner") {
            dinnerCalories += myData[i].Calories;
        }
        else if (myData[i].Type == "Snacks") {
            snackCalories += myData[i].Calories;
        }
        else if (myData[i].Type == "Exercise") {
            burnedCalories += myData[i].Calories;
        }
        let grossCalories = round(breakfastCalories + lunchCalories + dinnerCalories + snackCalories);
        let netCalories = round(breakfastCalories + lunchCalories + dinnerCalories + snackCalories - burnedCalories);

        calTotal.push([round(breakfastCalories), round(lunchCalories), round(dinnerCalories), round(snackCalories), grossCalories, netCalories]);
    }
}
```

**More Concise Example** (complete JSON data can be found [here](https://rentry.co/fh7g4))

```json
Example JSON
...
{
"Date": "Monday",
"Name": "Wild Pacific Sardines",
"Icon": "Fish",
"Type": "Lunch",
"Quantity": 85,
"Units": "Grams",
"Calories": 170
},
...
{
"Date": "Monday",
"Name": "Bacon, Sunday, Organic, Uncured",
"Icon": "Bacon",
"Type": "Dinner",
"Quantity": 1,
"Units": "Slice",
"Calories": 30
},
...
{
"Date": "Tuesday",
"Name": "Dressing, Vinaigrette, Lemon Pepper",
"Icon": "Oil",
"Type": "Lunch",
"Quantity": 2,
"Units": "Tablespoons",
"Calories": 200
},
```

For each day (Monday through Friday), add all `values` of `Calories` in `Type == Breakfast` together, all values of`Calories` in `Type == Lunch`, etc, and at the end of the day, present calorie totals in an array.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the desired output. Can you show what you're trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: One of those things when you've been at it for hours, and you forget that not everything is "obvious" to others! I am attempting to have calories added up to five groups (breakfastCalories, lunchCalories, etc, as seen under sample JSON). Right now, the code is running through and pulling out the values correctly, but they are all being added together (five days worth of data, marked in the JSON with the day of the week).

This is the source JSON data [link](https://rentry.co/fh7g4) I am attempting to create an array of the calories for each meal.

Comment: Thanks--what should the expected output look like literally? Can you [edit] to show it in the same format as the input? It's very hard to visualize it based on language. Are you trying to group the total calories for each day of the week?

Comment: The way the question is asked makes it seem like you already have the desired result, and you're just looking for a cleaner way to write it?

Comment: Thank you @ggorlen, I hope this makes it easier for everyone to understand the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
const data = fetch('https://api.npoint.io/0b9f68319d190f5d41ec')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then((output) => {
      return output;
}).catch(err => console.error(err));


data.then(items=>{
  let result ={};
  items.map(item=>{
    let Date = item.Date;
    let Type = item.Type;
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(Date) && result[Date].hasOwnProperty(Type)){
      result[Date][Type] += item.Calories;
    }else if(result.hasOwnProperty(Date)){
      result[Date][Type] = item.Calories;
    }else{
      result[Date]={};
      result[Date][Type] = item.Calories;
    }
  
    if(Object.keys(result[Date]).length == 5){ //each day have 5 prop (Breakfast,Lunch,.)
      result[Date]['netCalories'] = result[Date]['Breakfast']+result[Date]['Lunch']+result[Date]['Dinner']+result[Date]['Snacks'] - result[Date].Exercise;
      result[Date]['grossCalories'] = result[Date]['Breakfast']+result[Date]['Lunch']+result[Date]['Dinner']+result[Date]['Snacks'];
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for taking the time to code out a solution. I was stumbling a lot in my attempts to find a solution to creating key-value pairs from the JSON data.